# How do I run go-pg orm QueryContext function for nested struct?

Tags: go, orm, go-pg

When I try `QueryContext` function with nested `struct`, nested struct always get empty `struct`.
How I solve this?

```golang
type User struct {
    Firstname    *string    `json:"firstname" sql:",notnull"`
    Lastname     *string    `json:"lastname" sql:",notnull"`
}

type TestUser struct {
    User *User `json:"user"`
}

query := `
SELECT
users.firstname,
users.lastname
FROM
    test_users
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
        id, firstname, lastname
        FROM
            users
    ) users ON users.id = test_users.user_id
LIMIT 1
`

models := []TestUser{}
_, _ := conn.QueryContext(ctx, &models, query)
    return models, nil
```

If this is impossible with `go-pg` orm,
Is there any `orm` function to do that `sql`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the ORM model abstraction provided by [go-pg](https://github.com/go-pg/pg).

If you have two `structs` like these:

```golang
type User struct {
    Firstname    *string    `json:"firstname" sql:",notnull"`
    Lastname     *string    `json:"lastname" sql:",notnull"`
}

type TestUser struct {
    User *User `json:"user"`
}
```

Then you can populate your `models` slice using the [`.Model`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/pg.v6#DB.Model)

```golang
pgdb := pg.Connect(......)
models := []TestUser{}

err =pgdb.Model(&models).Relation("User").Select()
if err != nil {
    log.fatal(err)
}
```